# Quicker way of adding faces?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to face these into wedges. Is there a faster way of doing it?

[image]

Comment: If the spacing are even I guess you may use an *Array Modifier* for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the prism and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate it. Being in *Edit Mode* add an ***Array Modifier*** to the prism and set up the proper *relative offset* values. Check the ***Wire*** and ***Draw All*** checkboxes in *Display* panel of the *Object Data* header to help you match the prisms with a grid segments properly. Increase the modifier's *count* number and apply it. Join meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. In *Edit Mode* select one of the edges as pictured below, go to *Select*-->*Checker Deselect*, increase the *offset* if needed and delete selected edges to cut the holes for prisms. In the end select the whole object with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*. You may also recalculate normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
[image]